# Use the AWS API to send the url of a file to Lambda so it can be fetched and stored in S3?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-lambda, aws-api-gateway

I'm very new to Lambda.

My goal is to have an API endpoint where I can include an URL as argument (and probably a password), and have Lambda retrieve the file on that url, and save it into an S3 bucket.

I have the bucket ready, and have been reading all tutorials and examples I could find regarding lambda, but so far I can't figure out the pieces needed to get this to work.

Any guidance would be appreciated.

EDIT 1:
I got this far. This receives the url parameters from the API and checks the password, but it doesn't execute the get:

```
exports.handler = async (event) => {

    let url = '';
    let key = '';
    let out = 'empty';

    url = event["queryStringParameters"]['url'];
    key = event["queryStringParameters"]['key'];
    if (key != 'secret')
    {
        const response = {
            statusCode: 200,
            body: JSON.stringify('Unauthorized')
        };
        return response;        
    }
  
console.log("START");    
var https = require('https');

            https.get(url, function(res) {
                console.log("Got response: " + res.statusCode);
                const response = {
                    statusCode: 200,
                    body: JSON.stringify("success")
                    };
                return response;                
            }).on('error', function(e) {
                console.log("Got error: " + e.message);
                const response = {
                    statusCode: 200,
                    body: JSON.stringify("fail")
                };
                return response;
            }).end();  
    
    
    
    const response = {
        statusCode: 200,
        body: JSON.stringify(out)
    };
    return response;
};
```

Comment: First step is to confirm that you can receive the arguments. You can put `print()` statements in your Lambda code to confirm that it is correctly retrieving the URL. Then, you can add code to download the file, noting that AWS Lambda functions only have 512MB of storing space in `/tmp/`, so it won't work if the file is bigger than that. Then, add code to upload the file to S3. Finally, delete the temporary file to reclaim space for future executions. If you have a particular problem in these steps, please Edit your question to provide details of what you are doing and what problem you have.

Comment: @JohnRotenstein thanks. I was able to get the first step going. Posted my code so far.

Comment: When you try to run the get method, does it execute? if it does what's the response you are getting?